# Ocelot gateway doesnt want to apply microservice route

Tags: asp.net-core, microservices, ocelot

Separating monolithic app into several microservice now i'm interested how to run them all together.
So, I'm building ocelot gateway for this. And have some problems.

I tried to link one simple microservice with main api. If i go to the gateway route and query my microservices => i'll get 404. However, if i go to the uri of that microservice i'll get information.

Ocelot.json / ocelot.Development.json

```
{
  "Routes": [
    {
      "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
        {
          "Host": "localhost",
          "Port": 7001
        }
      ],
      "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/order",
      "DownstreamScheme": "https",
      "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/order",
      "UpstreamHttpMethod": [ "GET" ]
    }
  ],
  "GlobalConfiguration": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5001"
  }
}
```

Program:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
                {
                    loggerConfiguration.ReadFrom
                        .Configuration(hostingContext.Configuration);
                })
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    var environment = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

                    webBuilder.ConfigureAppConfiguration(config =>
                    {
                        config
                            .AddJsonFile("ocelot.json")
                            .AddJsonFile($"ocelot.{environment}.json");
                    });

                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
```

Startup:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseSerilogRequestLogging();
            app.UseCors(_AllowSpecificOrigin);

            app.UseSwagger(options =>
            {
                options.SerializeAsV2 = true;
            });

            app.UseSwaggerUI(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "ShoppingCart API");
                options.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    "default", 
                    "{controller=Products}/{action=GetAll}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseOcelot();
        }
```

Comment: What is your gateway url and what is your service url?

Comment: @tomredfern, i have my api on port 5001(https). another microservice on https://localhost:7001/order. So, i want to reach to that 7001 from my gateway 5001/order.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use:

```
Use app.UseOcelot().Wait();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).